# Create Simple Request using RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

I am having trouble using the RestKit api to create a simple RKRequest.

All i need is to make a PUT request with a provided url (which is a presigned amazon s3 url) and then attach some NSData to this request. I also want to set the delegate of this request.

I have tried many ways but none seem to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
RKParams* params = [RKParams params];
        [params setData:picInUse.imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpeg" forParam:@"image"];

uploadPictureRequest = [[RKRequest alloc] init];
uploadPictureRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:currentRequestURL];
uploadPictureRequest.method = RKRequestMethodPUT;
uploadPictureRequest.delegate = self;
uploadPictureRequest.params = params;

[uploadPictureRequest sendAsynchronously];
```

Edit:

The problem is that the delegate never gets called, it does get called for the RKCLient sent requests but not for this specific one.

When I NSLOG the url from the uploadpicture request i get NULL

```
NSLog(@"%@",uploadPictureRequest.URL);
```

and the message i recieve is:

> E restkit.network:RKRequest.m:623 Failed to send request to (null) due
>   to connection timeout. Timeout interval = 0.000000

Comment: did you implement proper protocol method that RestKit calls when response is available? does it get called? can you sniff your traffic with wireshark to verify that request gets to S3 and that proper 200 is returned?

Comment: What is your question? The code you have displayed looks fine

Comment: @IvorPrebeg the delegate doesnt get called, My implementation has the protocol working for the normal RKCLient. this code is actually withing that part, It will send a request to a very specific url which is totally different from the rkclient base url which is why i need to send it this way. It never gets called and if i print the URL property i receive Null.

Comment: Your url is probably malformed

Comment: try to monitor traffic with wireshark while debugging on simulator, it saves plenty of hours debugging on daily basis... you will see how does request look like and what response server gives you on network level

Comment: @PauldeLange if you put this as an answer ill accept it, there was an extra \n at the end of my url.